# html bookmark link some text doesn't appear

Tags: html, css

I created a link (Bookmark) to the same page. But here I face a problem. When I click the link on the link from the sidebar, it works fine but the headline or some part doesn't appear correctly on the display.

When I click the link the heading or some part is hidden for the header.[image]

But I want the full part will be displayed like this -[image]

How do I solve this issue?

```css
header{
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
background-color: #fff;
z-index: 5;
top: 0;
position: fixed;
}
nav{
width: 20%;
height: 100%;
top: 0;
left: 0;
position: fixed;
border-right: 1px solid #333;
}
article{
padding-top: 60px;
margin-left: 20%;
width: 60%;
}
aside{
width: 20%;
right: 0;
top: 0;
position: fixed;
border-left: 1px solid #333;
height: 100%;
padding-top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<nav></nav>

<article>
<a name="hyper-1"></a>
<h1>Hyper 1</h1>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>

<a name="hyper-2"></a>
<h1>Hyper 2</h1>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>

<a name="hyper-3"></a>
<h1>Hyper 3</h1>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>
</article>

<aside>
IN THIS CONTENT:
<a href="#hyper-1">Hyper-1</a><br/>
<a href="#hyper-2">Hyper-2</a><br/>
<a href="#hyper-3">Hyper-3</a><br/>
</aside>
```

Comment: You can use a scroll margin.

Like this: scroll-margin-top: 4rem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue is due to  elements are empty. they have no consistency and scroll to this element don't push following at the top of the div

to solve it an idea can be to have an hidden after element after `<a>` to push following as expected when scroll to this anchor point

```
article a::after {
  content: ' ';
  padding: 12px;
}
```

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 5;
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
}

nav {
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  border-right: 1px solid #333;
}

article {
  padding-top: 60px;
  margin-left: 20%;
  width: 60%;
}

article a::after {
  content: ' ';
  padding: 12px;
}

aside {
  width: 20%;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
  border-left: 1px solid #333;
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<nav></nav>

<article>
  <a name="hyper-1"></a>
  <h1>Hyper 1</h1>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>

  <a name="hyper-2"></a>
  <h1>Hyper 2</h1>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>

  <a name="hyper-3"></a>
  <h1>Hyper 3</h1>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
</article>

<aside>
  IN THIS CONTENT:
  <a href="#hyper-1">Hyper-1</a><br/>
  <a href="#hyper-2">Hyper-2</a><br/>
  <a href="#hyper-3">Hyper-3</a><br/>
</aside>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get it correctly, you need to scroll on top of the page any time it gets loaded... since it may be loaded from a link coming from the very same page.

One solution is to scroll on top of the page as soon as it's ready:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(this).scrollTop(0);
});
```